# Restore large backup on SQL Server's VM currently replicating to a remote VM both Hyper-V

Tags: sql-server, virtual-machine, replication, hyper-v

I am looking for ideas to restore a large backup on a VM hosting SQL Server that is replicating to another VM in a remote location. Restoring it will replicate the restored backup consuming a lot of the bandwidth between both sites.

Both sites are in same city. Would it work if I pause the replication, restore the DB on both local and remote VMs, then resume replication? This will save from wasting bandwidth.

I know I can break the replication, restore the DB, export the local VM and import into the remote site. It would work, but there are other DBs on the VM server. The exported VM image would be huge. The other issue with this. I will need to repeat this process when moving other databases into the local VM which does not sound like a good idea.

Is there a better way?

Comment: off-topic - belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @SMor I didn't know about dba.stackexchange.com. Should I post it there too? thanks,